# What is the word for Compliance using -tion or city

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-request

I want to know the family of word `Compliance`. This work I am using show something `success`.

I have list with product's state, list items are Compliance, Pending, failed.

Now I need `label` for list. As of now using `Compliance`. I am thing it should be something like `Compliancetion or Compliancity.`

Can anyone help me

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not clear how this is a problem related to learning the English language. It reads more like a "variable naming"-type problem, which is off-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use "Compliancetion or Compliancity". They are not words.

You could call the category "**Compliance**", which is a noun, and the individual terms describing the product's current state could be these adjectives:

**compliant** / **in compliance**  (the product complies)
**pending**
**failed** / **non-compliant** (the product does not comply)

If you can use longer terms, "compliant" is equivalent to "In compliance".

Comment: Are you saying label name "In compliance"?

Comment: I am saying that "in compliance" means the same as "compliant". Don't  use it for the category that includes all three states. I clarified the answer a bit